# Fullcalendar not showing in a modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar jQuery plugin to show calendar.

What happening is it's not working on a bootstrap modal.
I've tried somethings that I got from internet, but still no luck.

Someone please help me.

```
<a href="#" id="see-doc-cal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#doc-cal" >See Doctor Calendar</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="doc-cal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Doctor's Appointments</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="doctor-detail-wrap">
          <div id="doctor-calendar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="doc-update" value="Update"> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="plist-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Main.js

```
$("#doctor-calendar").fullCalendar({
  header:{
    left:'prev',
    center:'title',
    right:'next'
  },
  defaultView:'agendaDay'
});

$('#doc-cal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $("#doctor-calendar").fullCalendar('render');
});
```

Also tried with this

```
$(document).on("click","#see-doc-cal",function(){

  $('#doctor-calendar').fullCalendar();
});
```

Comment: Is the full calendar is not being displayed when modal pop opens up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only added `$("#doc-cal").modal(open);`.

Got to open the modal to see it, right?
Or maybe your problem was about the load-up of the libraries...

Anyway, it is working great in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JJVbpj?editors=1010)

Comment: No, there's an anchor tag that opens up the modal,,

Comment: So check the libraries load... Because it works in Codepen. Error in console?

Comment: No errors in console.. i think its because when the page loads, the modal is hidden, when we click on anchor tag the dom is changed, but our calendar doesn't pick that up, something like that.

Comment: I updated the Codepen to use a button opening the modal... Still works. What do you mean with "hidden"? Using CSS ? If so... Just use `.show()`. I updated the Codepen again.

Comment: I tryed with you anchor toggle... Works too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149320/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-master-mind).

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that my parent div was hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a very simple trick;

first - i find the class who add 'hidden' property in the modal (in my case, i'm using semantic ui, 'modal' class are responsable for that).

```
<div class = 'ui <!--long modal--> full-calendar'> 
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

Then, in jquery code i do that:

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

```
    dayClick: function() {



    },
    weekends: false,
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    locale: 'pt-br',
    render: true
```

});

$(".ui.full-calendar").addClass('long modal');// you can put here your hidden modal class.

that way the calendar is rendered first and then are hidden, showing when the modal is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code to render fullCalendar since it is hidden in the modal pop up.

```
$('#doc-cal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#doctor-calendar").fullCalendar('render');
})
```

Fullcalendar is not displayed when the element which contain it is hidden in page. See the working example.

```js
$('#doc-cal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $("#doctor-calendar").fullCalendar('render');
})

$("#doctor-calendar").fullCalendar({
    header:{
      left:'prev',
      center:'title',
      right:'next'
    },
    defaultView:'agendaDay'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a href="#" id="see-doc-cal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#doc-cal" >See Doctor Calendar</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="doc-cal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Doctor's Appointments</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="doctor-detail-wrap">
          <div id="doctor-calendar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="doc-update" value="Update"> -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="plist-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why this not working in my system?? does the sequence of including libraries makes a difference?? I mean first im including my css files than before closing body tag im inclding all my js scripts.

Comment: That's actually good practise. Issue might be something else.